# Swift detect return key pressed without using textFieldDidEndEditing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

Is there a way to detect that the return key was pressed on the keyboard without using `textFieldDidEndEditing`. `textFieldDidEndEditing` is also triggered if you for example perform a segue which dismisses the keyboard.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The below delegate is called when you press the return key.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("return pressed")
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return false
}
```

Comment: Can't believe i forgot about that method, it was even in my `UIViewController`! Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Updated for swift 4:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("return pressed")
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return false
}
```